# Are the Application life cycles for Windows phone 7 and 8 the same?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, application-lifecycle

Are the Application life cycles for Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 the same? If not, please guide me to the differences in the application life cycles of both.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. [MSDN article on app activation and deactivation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) has a note:

> Applies to Windows Phone 8 | Windows Phone OS 7.1